# Is there a way to run a .exe compiled with MinGW without having MinGW installed?

Tags: mingw

I have a .exe compiled using g++ and it runs without problem. But if I want to distribute it, it will require MinGW installed. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I use MinGW-64 header files and libraries to cross compile Windows applications under Linux. I link the binaries statically so that I don't have to send anything other than the .exe files to a Windows box. I use my clang/LLVM based toolchain (http://ellcc.org) to do the build rather than gcc, but gcc should be able to do the same thing. I've used this technique to compile all the ELLCC tools (C/C++ compiler, binutils, gdb) and it has worked very well.

Comment: While it is true that static linking can be used to limit the need to distribute additional DLLs, along with your application, I don't believe it is possible to eliminate them entirely. For example, in multithreaded C++ code on Windows, destructors associated with thread termination require a DLL unloading hook to run.  If you eliminate all use of non-system DLLs -- you cannot eliminate system DLL dependencies -- your (multithreaded) application may leak memory on thread termination.

Answer (score 0):

## To make your exe run on other windows-systems, compile it statically and do not link to dlls

Yes you can compile your code to a standalone .exe file with mingw.
I do this, cross-compiling c++ code on linux and run it on windows machines.

The point is, you have to link statically.

- This might include linking to a few more libs than in the dynamic case (compare this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64389156/7128154)).
- probably you need the flags `-fPIC -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++`
- for all libraries you link to (i.e. wherever you need a command of the form `-lmylib`), ensure that the corresponding file `libmylib.lib` exists in the library path of your system and that it is not `libmylib.dll`. You can not compile a standalone code with a dll linked.
- If you have to link to a `.dll`, either redistribute it as well (in the same folder as the exe) or get a static compiled version of the library (this might require you to compile the library yourself). On linux there are some static versions of mingw-packages available. For instance "mingw32-LibRaw-static.noarch : Static version of the MinGW Windows LibRaw library"

A few links about the g++ compiler and linker options:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.3.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options
- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.2.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options
- http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/ld/Options.html

Answer (score -1):

Your application will run perfectly well on other computers, without requiring MinGW to be installed; what will be required is for you to distribute any DLLs from the MinGW compiler suite, (likely the C++ library DLL, and maybe also the standard C library DLL), upon which your application depends, along with it.

Do note that these DLLs are licensed under the GPL, so your application may need to be licensed under a compatible licence; (IANAL, so you will need to seek legal advice if you plan commercial distribution).  Also, you must make provision to distribute GCC source, (and maybe your own source too), to any user of your application who may request it.

Comment: The DLLs are public domain and/or MIT-licensed.

Comment: What DLLs are public domain, or MIT licensed, @csl? The libgcc and libstdc++ DLLs furnished by MinGW.org are distributed under the GPL licensing terms. Apart from `mingwm10.dll`, (which I don't think is even needed with GCC-4.x compiled binaries), there are no DLLs distributed for default support of MinGW compiled executables, which might qualify as public domain or MIT licensed.

Comment: The last part is wrong :-) See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.license.any_program --- for example, libstdc++ has an exemption clause that lets you _use_ it, even for proprietary programs.

Comment: The exception clause doesn't exempt from the terms of the licence, when _distributing_ the DLL.  There has even been some doubt expressed on the MinGW-Users mailing list by Eli Zaretskii, in consultation with no lesser a personality than Richard Stallman himself, that the exception applies to dynamically linked code at all; IIRC, RMS holds the view that it applies only to statically linked code, and dynamic linking (which then requires DLL distribution) remains governed by the GPL. Therefore, unless you can cite legal precedent, you cannot assert that my _warning_ is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

I was looking for the exact same solution. This is what works:

- Compile Windows executable as normal using MinGW
- To run the executable on Windows, you need these DLLs:

  - libgcc_s_seh-1.dll
  - libssp-0.dll
  - libstdc++-6.dll
  - libwinpthread-1.dll

On my system, I found them in `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/bin/`. Your programs may not need *all* of them. Experiment.

**The following part is not correct**

As for [MinGW licensing terms](http://www.mingw.org/license), it seems that the MinGW libraries are either **public domain** or **MIT-licensed**, meaning that there is absolutely no problem with redistributing these DLLs — only the development tools are covered by the GPL.

**Update**

So the redistribution of the DLLs is not straight-forward. The licensing terms I mentioned are for MinGW itself, I believe. You are in any case allowed to *use* these libraries, but *redistributing* would need additional care, unless your sofware is released under a license that conforms with the eligibility terms of the GPLv3 + the runtime exception clause. If I find out more, I'll update the answer.

Comment: 100% ___wrong___ on the licensing. Every one of those you've itemized is GPL, (or possibly LGPL) -- certainly ___not___ public domain, or MIT.

Comment: Ok, the public domain part is certainly wrong for the DLLs. But winpthread seems to be distributed under a combined MIT and 3-clause BSD license (from what I could find). libstdc++ is distributed under GPLv3 with the GCC Runtime Library Exception, meaning you can certainly _use_ it, even for proprietary programs (redistribution is another matter). As for libssp and libgcc_s_seh, I haven't looked into them yet.

Comment: Okay. I overlooked that `libwinpthread-1.dll` isn't a GCC component library, but it isn't MinGW either; it may be mingw-w64, but that renegade project isn't MinGW.