# Linking OpenCV 4.1.0, include works, libs doesn't

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

After changing Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04 and OpenCV from 3.4.1 to 4.1.0 i can't  compiled... anything

Step by step:

I downloaded source code from github, set those flags:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib/modules cmake -DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF -DBUILD_opencv_cudacodec=OFF -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D WITH_CUDA=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 -D WITH_QT=OFF -D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF ..
```

compiled it and installed

Next, I created simple program:

```
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream> 

using namespace cv; 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    cout << "V: " << CV_VERSION << endl;
    return 0; 
}
```

Compiled it with this command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv4` -g -o main
```

and get working executable main:

```
V: 4.1.0-pre
```

But when I added one line with Mat

```
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream> 

using namespace cv; 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    cout << "V: " << CV_VERSION << endl;
    Mat frame;
    return 0; 
}
```

I got more errors than my terminal can display

I suppose, that files like libopencv_core.a are not linking

This method linking libraries always worked for me, I don't know where to look for a mistakes

Any clues, advice?

Edit:

Here is the begining of my error (full error contains +4500 lines, if it's necessary I can add .txt with full error)

```
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(system.cpp.o): In function `cv::ipp::getIPPSingleton()':
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3ippL15getIPPSingletonEv+0xdb): undefined reference to `ippicvGetCpuFeatures'
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3ippL15getIPPSingletonEv+0x16e): undefined reference to `ippicvSetCpuFeatures'
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3ippL15getIPPSingletonEv+0x173): undefined reference to `ippicvGetEnabledCpuFeatures'
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3ippL15getIPPSingletonEv+0x1ba): undefined reference to `ippicviGetLibVersion'
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3ippL15getIPPSingletonEv+0x263): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3ippL15getIPPSingletonEv+0x270): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_settype'
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3ippL15getIPPSingletonEv+0x283): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_destroy'
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3ippL15getIPPSingletonEv+0x2a1): undefined reference to `ippicvInit'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(system.cpp.o): In function `cv::getInitializationMutex()':
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv22getInitializationMutexEv+0x63): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_init'
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv22getInitializationMutexEv+0x70): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_settype'
system.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv22getInitializationMutexEv+0x83): undefined reference to `pthread_mutexattr_destroy'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution, this flag was guilty: `-D BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF`, after removing it everything worked fine

Answer (score 2):

I would run `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv4` in bash and check if the linker parameters are correct, and the paths/libraries exist. `make install` should tell you where the libs are copied to (`/usr/local/lib` or something like that). If `#include` works, include directories are *usually* properly set.

Comment: `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv4`
gave this answer:
`-I/usr/local/include/opencv -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lopencv_cudabgsegm -lopencv_cudaobjdetect` ... (then many other lopencv_)
it seems that everything is linked well
I modified my question and added part of an error, because its my only clue

Comment: You also get pthread linker errors, which usually means pthread isn't installed, but then you shouldn't be able to build opencv? compiler flags look good, at least what you wrote. I am also unsure how opencv handles the ippi stuff/where it comes from. You could also try to disable some parameters when building opencv (`-D WITH_CUDA=ON -D WITH_TBB=ON -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 -D WITH_CUBLAS=1`)

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem. It solves after making

`sudo ldconfig`

from the same folder I triggered the installation.

Give it a try, and good look.

Answer (score 1):

While switching to dynamic linking may have solved this problem, you generally have to link against the missing libraries in a static build.

In this case you have to link at least against `pthread` and `libippicv` according to your error messages.

Answer (score 0):

## static linking needs to include more dependencies

Your code

```
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream> 

using namespace cv; 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    cout << "V: " << CV_VERSION << endl;
    Mat frame;
    return 0; 
}
```

builds on my system (win 8.1 64bit, opencv 4.2.0. compiled with BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF, compiler mingw-w64) with the batch script

```
set gcc="C:\Program Files (x86)\mingw-w64\i686-8.1.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v6-rev0\mingw32\bin\g++.exe"
set path_opencv=C:\opencv-4.2.0-vc14_vc15\opencv\build
%gcc% code.cpp -I"%path_opencv%\include" -L"%path_opencv%\x64\mingw-w64\lib" -lopencv_core420 -lz -lpthread
```

As discussed on the opencv answers platform [after turning BUILD_SHARED_LIBS to OFF , there are too many undefined references](https://answers.opencv.org/question/198721/after-turning-build_shared_libs-to-off-there-are-too-many-undefined-references/?answer=198727) static linking does not forward dependencies. Therefore we need to additionally link the libraries `-lz -lpthread`.

Further, **the order of the -l... flags is important**. This means open dependencies are collected and satisfied by the following libraries. Read [Specify the libraries for the linker to use](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use) for more info.

### correction to your code

It is sufficient to include `#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>` instead of `highgui` and `imgproc`. This is as cv::Mat is defined in `core`. For this reason the flag `-lopencv_core420` is enough and `-lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc` is not needed.